# Insert image in mysql using LOAD_FILE() not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert image into mysql database. I am using the following query. But the query is not working. If i remove the image insertion part it works. Where is the problem? Can anyone help

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable ( `username`, `password`, `firstname`, `lastname`,`email`,`pic`) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$email',LOAD_FILE('img/pro.jpg'));";
```

Comment: You must debug the query, checking the appropriate error method for the MySQL API you are using. That would be `mysql_error(), mysqli_error(), $pdo->errorInfo()` etc. I suspect you are using the bare deprecated `mysql_query()` based on your variables in the query. `LOAD_FILE()` requires special privileges. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Comment: yes i am using mysql_query().

Comment: What should i use to insert image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `LOAD_FILE()` you must have `FILE` privilege. If you have so, then try using absolute path like below

```
INSERT INTO mytable ( `username`, `password`, `firstname`, `lastname`,`email`,`pic`) 
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$email',LOAD_FILE('D:\img\pro.jpg'));
```

(OR)

If `img` is the root path then it should look like

```
INSERT INTO mytable ( `username`, `password`, `firstname`, `lastname`,`email`,`pic`) 
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$email',LOAD_FILE('/img/pro.jpg'));
```

Comment: Then it should be clear in the post. Editing post after an answer invalidates the answer. Anyways, see edit in answer if that helps.